# Firefox Error: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins

I'm having an issue on Firefox version 22.0 in which it won't load a slideshow on the following site: http://www.onstreammedia.com

When I looked at the firefox web console I'm getting the following error:

[10:34:15.831] NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Component is not available @ http://www.onstreammedia.net/scripts/jquery.themepunch.kenburn.min.js:1

Not quite sure where to start looking for the problem. The site loads fine in just about every other browser. Funny thing is that it's worked great for the past year in firefox up until yesterday. Any ideas as to what may be causing this? I wish I could provide more information but I'm at a loss as to where to even look for any clues as to what's going on. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:  I used http://jsbeautifier.org/ to clean up the code and after further inspection it seems the error lies on line 746 which has the following code:

```
O.drawImage(f[0], y, g, B, j);
```

Still not quite sure as to what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the min.js with a non-minified version, which may help you identify the error?